# How to traverse object with dynamic keys in Paw?

Tags: paw-app

Let's say we have the following JSON response:

```
{
  "abcd1234": {
   "foo": "bar"
 }
}
```

How would "bar" be accessed in a *response parsed body* value? In the response, `"abcd1234"` could be anything. But we want the first key in the object (in JavaScript this would be `Object.keys(res)[0]`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paw makes it easy to parse JSON (and XML) responses and access subfields via their key-path.

This documentation article may help: https://paw.cloud/docs/advanced/reuse-values-from-previous-responses

**Insert the Response Parsed Body dynamic value**

[image: Insert the Response Parsed Body dynamic value]

**Set the input request and extract the needed value**

[image: Set the input request and extract the needed value]

In your example, the key path will be:

```
abcd1234.foo
```

Though, it seems like you need to access the path without knowing the key before hand. If so, one way would be to use a JavaScript snippet to be able to achieve the behavior you want.

On any field, you may right-click and pick **Extensions > JS Script**.

Here's a snippet that may fit your needs:

```
function evaluate(context){
    var request = context.getCurrentRequest();
    var exchange = request.getLastExchange();
    var body = JSON.parse(exchange.responseBody);
    var key = Object.keys(body)[0];
    var value = body[key].foo;
    return value;
};
```

Comment: Thank you! The JavaScript is exactly what I needed. Can this be stored in a variable, which is then globally accessible throughout the Paw project, after a request has finished, as well?